# Для чего перед символьным литералом стоит буква f?

Tags: python

Для чего перед символьным литералом стоит буква f?

```
n = int(input())
print(f'The next number for the number {n} is {n+1}.')
print(f"The previous number for the number {n} is {n-1}.")
```

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/f-strings

Answer (score 1):

С помощью этой буквы можно вставить в строку значение переменной. Для этого нужно переменную обернуть в фигурные скобочки.

Comment: Спасибо, я поняла.

Answer (score 0):

Если ее не поставить, то внутрь строки нельзя будет добавить переменную.
В твоем примере добавлена переменная {n} в таком формате и операции с ней.

Comment: Спасибо, я поняла.